# VBA macro - Clicking the button part of code does not run

Tags: vba, excel

So, I have been reading and digging a bit around how to solve this problem and I havent found a working solution.
I have tried:
-checking i have no "active-Sheets/Workbook" references.
-Checking method names are ok.

This is [image: a capture where you can see the troubling part of the code]

I am a newbie in VBA so i stole the function from somewhere and made a little tweak to it. Function (and whole code) is working properly when i hit the play button in the vba console, but it does not when i click the activeX button.
Any idea how to proceed? 
Thanks in advance!

Here is the code in the button_click():

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
      Módulo1.Formatting_Number (Sheets("Hoja5").Range("AB8:AB23"))
      Módulo1.WhereToInsertRow
    End Sub
```

And here is the code in the module, that gets called from the button:

```
    Public Function LastRec(Myrng As Range, g As Integer)
      For x = Myrng(1).Row To Myrng(Myrng.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If Cells(x, Myrng.Column).Value = Cells(x + 1, Myrng.Column).Value Then GoTo continue
        If Cells(x, Myrng.Column).Value = g Then
            LastRec = x
            Exit Function
        End If
    LastRec = CStr(g) & "Not FOUND"
    continue:
      Next x
    End Function
    Public Sub WhereToInsertRow()
      Dim g As Integer
      For g = 2 To 7
         Sheets("Hoja5").Range("AB" & g + 6) = LastRec(Sheets("Hoja5").Range("O:O"), g)
      Next g
      For g = 14 To 23
         Sheets("Hoja5").Range("AB" & g).Value = LastRec(Sheets("Hoja5").Range("O:O"), (g + 87))
      Next g
    End Sub

    Public Sub Formatting_Number(rng As Range)
        Dim cel As Range
        For Each cel In rng
           cel.NumberFormat = "0"
        Next cel
    End Sub
```

P.D: In case you are curious, original function returned last occurrence of a value in a column starting from last cell, i tweaked it so now it starts from first cell.

Comment: Please can you post your code here rather than a screenshot?

Comment: Sorry.. I've added the code now

Comment: Insert a Breakpoint in the first line of your CommanButton1_click Sub and check that the Sub is being called. You can then click F8 to follow the process to see where it breaks down.

Comment: Thanks. The fact that it works from the editor but not from the button suggests it may be a problem with a sheet reference. `LastRec` has no sheet references so that may be the problem.

Comment: I guess it may have to be with SJR answer, because other parts of the code run perfectly (Anyway, just in case i checked the sub is being called and it is being called.)
So, I will try to reference sheets inside LastRec
But, is not getting referenced when I define "Myrng" as "Sheets("Hoja5").Range("O:O")?

Comment: Yes but the issue is likely to be around `Cells(x, Myrng.Column).Value`.

Comment: Btw think your code can be shortened quite a lot.

Comment: Great! I didnt see that part!.. Problem solved! Thanks SJR
Feel free to enlighten me if you want.. I am recently crawling in VBA (and in programming)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could tighten it up thus. Better still to specify other parameters such as ranges and/or sheets.

```
Public Function LastRec(Myrng As Range, g As Integer)
    Dim x As Long, rFind As Range

    With Myrng
        Set rFind = .Find(What:=g, After:=.Cells(.Count), Lookat:=xlWhole, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not rFind Is Nothing Then
            LastRec = rFind.Row
        Else
            LastRec = g & " not FOUND"
        End If
    End With

End Function

Public Sub WhereToInsertRow()
    Dim g As Integer, r As Range

    With Sheets("Hoja5")
        Set r = .Range("O1", .Range("O" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With

    For g = 2 To 7
       Sheets("Hoja5").Range("AB" & g + 6) = LastRec(r, g)
    Next g
    For g = 14 To 23
       Sheets("Hoja5").Range("AB" & g).Value = LastRec(r, g + 87)
    Next g
End Sub

Public Sub Formatting_Number(rng As Range)
  rng.NumberFormat = "0"
End Sub

Sub x()
    Module1.Formatting_Number Sheets("Hoja5").Range("A8:A23")
    Module1.WhereToInsertRow
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Módulo1.Formatting_Number (Sheets("Hoja5").Range("AB8:AB23"))
  Módulo1.WhereToInsertRow
End Sub


Public Function LastRec(Myrng As Range, g As Integer)
  .
  .
  .
End Function
```

Your `LastRec` function requires 2 parameters, neither of which is optional. You're only passing 1.

There are probably other issues, but that's a starter.

Also, change

```
Módulo1.Formatting_Number (Sheets("Hoja5").Range("AB8:AB23"))
```

to

```
Módulo1.Formatting_Number Sheets("Hoja5").Range("AB8:AB23")
```

You don't want that outer pair of parens () that will mess you up.

Comment: I will make that change, thanks!

In respect to LastRec, it gets called inside WhereToInsertRow() sub, and has got two parameters.
My fault for not writing clear enough..
Problem solved anyway, it was that range inside LastRec without proper references..